# Adding nssdb certificate from an install script

Tags: chrome, ssl, packaging, certificates, nss

I am trying to write an script (postinst for a .deb package) that will install a secure websockets (wss:) application and a certificate that allows access from the Chrome browser. The developer has this working by adding a certificate to the user's nssdb using `certutil -A -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb`

How do I do this from an installer script? I've tried `sudo -u $SUDO_USER`, which works if the user uses the commandline `sudo dpkg` but doesn't work from something like Ubuntu Software Centre which runs as root. Is there a better way of doing it such as a system-wide database. I tried `/etc/pki/nssdb` which I'd seen somewhere but that wasn't being picked up by Chrome.

Comment: You can't change users' configuration from a package management script. You can *try*, but that will only mess things up, it will overwrite user preferences, it won't affect users created in the future, etc. Just don't do that. A system-wide database, if there is one, is the only real solution. Doesn't `/etc/ssl/certs` serve your purpose?

Comment: I use `update-ca-certificates` to install our certificate from `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` but that doesn't seem to be enough; Chrome gives an error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when it tries to connect to the libwebsockets based server.

Comment: Best web info I've seen regarding this topic: http://blog.xelnor.net/firefox-systemcerts/

The above entry also references: https://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS_Shared_DB_Howto